# Custom DataAnnotation Binding Wrong Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I have a C# app with a custom `RequiredIf` DataAnnotation implementation as follows:

```
public class RequiredIf : RequiredAttribute {
    private String PropertyName { get; set; }
    private Object DesiredValue { get; set; }

    public RequiredIf (String property_name, Object desired_value) {
        PropertyName = property_name;
        DesiredValue = desired_value;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid (object value, ValidationContext context) {
        Object instance = context.ObjectInstance;
        Type type = instance.GetType();
        Object prop = type.GetProperty(PropertyName);
        Object property_value = type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance, null);
        if ( property_value.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString() ) {
            ValidationResult result = base.IsValid(value, context);
            return result;
        }


        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

This appears to work in nearly every case.

I have a ViewModel that I am trying to validate. The ViewModel has a child class. The basic implementation is:

```
public class ViewModel {
    .........
    public class ChildObject {
        [RequiredIf("FieldToCheck", false)]    // note that it's only required if the value is FALSE!
        DateTime? ConditionalField { get; set; }  // could be NULL
        Boolean FieldToCheck { get; set; }
    }
    ..........
}
```

When I submit the form with `FieldToCheck` set to true, my ViewModel validation still fails on this `RequiredIf`. I can view the value in the ViewModel variable in the controller and verify that it is `true`. However, I can set a breakpoint in the DataAnnotation's `IsValid` method and see in the debugger that the `FieldToCheck` is *false* - NOT what I submitted!

Is the Model Binder binding wrong? If so, why? And why is the bound value *incorrect* in the validator, but *correct* in the controller?

This is causing my ViewModel validation to fail *whenever* that DateTime field is left blank (NULL gets submitted). But if that Boolean is false, I don't even *show* the DateTime field in my form -- I don't *want* the user to submit anything in that field.

EDIT: This seems to happen *only with Booleans*, but it happens consistently regardless of where the Boolean/ConditionalField are created.

Does the Model Binder not bind Boolean members prior to validation?

EDIT2:

In the view, I have a standard form that I use to post the data:

```
@Model ViewModel

@using ( Html.BeginForm("Create", "Controller", FormMethod.Post ) {

    .........

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FieldToCheck, Model.FieldToCheckList)

    .........

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

}
```

The Controller:

```
public class Controller : Controller {

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create (ViewModel view_model) {
        // I set a breakpoint here, and if I submit FieldToCheck = true, the debugger shows that FieldToCheck is, indeed, true.
        if ( ModelState.IsValid ) {
            // save to db
            return View();
        }
        return View();
   }
}
```

I have a method that initializes fields in the ViewModel before rendering the form, and in it, I set `FieldToCheckList` as follows:

```
view_model.FieldToCheckList = new List<SelectListItem> {
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = Boolean.TrueString },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = Boolean.FalseString }
}
```

So I am using a `select` to populate the value. However, I have tried multiple other form elements (including statically setting a `HiddenFor` to true) and it still results in the same problem. If I set a breakpoint in the `IsValid` method in the `RequiredIf` validator, all of my boolean values are false, regardless of submitted data. If I set a breakpoint in the `Create` method in `Controller`, my boolean values are set correctly.

I have also tested both `Boolean` and `bool` data types. It doesn't seem to affect anything.

EDIT4:

I didn't actually figure out the *cause* of the problem or a real solution, but I did find a workaround.

So, apparently the issue occurs when I do `RequiredIf(AnyBooleanValue, AnythingButTrue)`. If the `DesiredValue` is set to *anything* except `true`, the Model Binder sets *all* boolean values in the ViewModel to the default value - `false` - regardless of what is submitted. I have tried multiple things - `RequiredIf(FieldToCheck, "False")`, `RequiredIf(FieldToCheck, !true)`, etc. None work. But if I do `RequiredIf(FieldToCheck, true)`, the values get bound correctly!

So the workaround is to add a new field:

```
public class ViewModel {
    public Boolean FieldToCheck { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsConditionalFieldRequired { get; set; }
    [RequiredIf("IsConditionalFieldRequired",true)]
    public string ConditionalField { get; set; }
}
```

In the view, I have `IsConditionalFieldRequired` as a hidden field, and whenever `FieldToCheck` is changed, I use jQuery to set `IsConditionalFieldRequired` to the inverse of `FieldToCheck`.

(I added this as an edit instead of an answer because I don't think it's a true solution, just a viable workaround. Obviously it's not the most eloquent way to get things done.)

Comment: Are you posting the form using mvc or are you posting via javascript?

Comment: I'm posting the data using a standard HTML form. So yes, I'm using MVC. It seems that the Model Binder just isn't binding Boolean values correctly, as the debugger shows (in the IsValid method) that *all* Booleans are set to false; however, the values are bound correctly in the controller method.

Comment: Can you add the relevant html?

Comment: Check the values in `if ( property_value.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString() ) {` - possibly a case issue - `"False"` vs `"false"` - but you would be far better off actually using the boolean values instead of its string values

Comment: Note, as soon as you're using C# 6, switch to `nameof(FieldToCheck)` instead of `"FieldToCheck"` so you get type awareness and renaming safety!

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks but I actually tried that. The problem is 1) the conditional statement isn't *failing* when it should *succeed* - it's *succeeding* when it should *fail*! and 2) The debugger is actually showing the wrong value -- it appears that *all booleans* in the ViewModel are being assigned the default value of `false` regardless of what value is actually submitted. The weird part is that, though the value is wrong during validation, it's *right* in the controller method.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I just ran into the same problem today, where I was using a `RequiredIf` attribute and the `ValidationContext.ObjectInstance` properties did not have the correct bound values.

In my case, it turned out to be due to my view model class having a constructor which set some default property values.  Inside the custom attribute code, the property values were those set in the constructor, but in the controller, the property values were from the posted form.

I worked around it by removing the constructor and setting default values in the view instead.